# Add Extra object inside loop in Mule Dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-component, dataweave

How to add additional object inside array in dataweave. Please find the input and expected response. I stored the below input in flowVars

Input:

```
 {
    "calculate": [{
    "rate": 10.4500,
    "margin": 0.000,
    "amount": 1000
   }]
}
```

If the input amount is greater than 1000, add additional one more object along with the original one. Response should look like below

Response:

```
{
  "calculate": [{
    "actualRate": 10.4500,
    "amount": 1000
},
{
    "actualRate": 10.4500,
    "amount": null
  }]
}
```

Dataweave: (not sure how to add extra object in the response above)

```
 %dw 1.0
 %output application/java
 ---
 {
   calculate: flowVars.calculate map {
    actualRate:$.rate,
    amount:$.amount
 }
}
```

Could anyone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could do what you need:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
 ---
flowVars.calculate map {
       calculate:[
            { 
              actualRate:$.rate,
              amount:$.amount
             },
             {
                actualRate:$.rate,
                amount : null
             }
           ] when $.amount >= 1000
           otherwise [
                { 
                  actualRate:$.rate,
                  amount:$.amount
                 }
           ]

}
```